# VS Community 2015 - No Windows Phone Emulator Installed

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I get the following error when trying to build (Debug > Windows Phone > Device) the default Cordova TypeScript project :

`No Windows Phone 8 emulators installed.  Please install Visual Studio 2013 with Windows Phone 8 tools selected to install the emulators`
[image]

Note: I was using the release candiate of Visual Studio 2015 and just installed the trial version of Visual Studio Community 2015.

Installing Visual Studio 2013 Windows Phone 8 tools can't be the correct solution.

Comment: Are you on Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1.  Unfortunately, I'm thinking a clean install is the real solution as it's worked for previous version of VS2015.

Comment: @DeanB_Develop agree. I think you need a clean install.

Comment: Uninstalled VS2015 Community, reinstalled and tried rebuilding.  Same error appears when trying to Debug > Windows Phone 8 > Device.  The same error occurs when using Debug > Windows Phone 8 > Emulators

Comment: I found my problem.  In previous versions of VS2015 I could debug on my USB connected phones/devices using Debug > Windows Phone 8 > Device. With the current version (community 2015 rtm) I need to use Debug > Windows Phone (Universal) > Device. Tested and confirmed

Comment: I don't see why you accepted Subhag Oak's answer he totally missed you point.  Thanks for your solution though.  It worked.

Comment: @pdschuller Subhag Oak is right in that you need VS 2013 installed to deploy to a Windows phones for testing.  

My solutions was to use Windows Phone (universal) as the solutions platform when testing APPS on Windows 8.1 and windows 10. Now I can test apps on Windows devices without the Visual Studio 2013 install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for upgrading to the RTM VS 2015. Unfortunately, you do require VS2013 for Windows 8 emulators to be installed. They aren't available on VS 2015 or there is no stand-alone installer for the emulators. But you should be able to deploy your Windows 8 application on Windows 8.1 emulators, if that helps.

Comment: The problem with Windows 8.1 is that the PickSingleFileAsync-method is deprecated, in favor of PickSingleFileAndContinue. Since this method is "difficult" for Cordova use (requires saving the app state), Cordova must use a custom camera instead of the one provided by the OS. I'm willing to sacrifice 512 MB devices (for which this API change was made), but that does not help because the PickSingleFileAsync-method isn't available anyway. I'm only hoping Windows 10 Phone is able to run the Android version of my app. :-(

Comment: @frodeborli, I updated the Camera plugin (CameraProxy.js) to work with Windows Phone 8.1 using PickSingleFileAndContinue. I haven't submitted fixes to the official repo yet, but you can find the code here: https://github.com/Mikejo5001/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaUploadImages

Comment: Did anybody tried to install emulators Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk ?

Comment: But the emulators *are* installed by VS2015 setup, and I have them installed! Yet the VS2015 Update 3 IDE does not find them... :(

Answer (score 6):

I've downloaded and installed wpsdkv80_enu1.iso from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471. It is Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and Emulator and **it's working fine** with Visual Studio 2015 Community

If you want to only test universal apps, you don't need to download WP SDK 8.0.
You can debug universal apps directly from VS by switching platform to Windows Phone(universal) and choose Windows 8.1 Emulator. But it expects **Emulators for Windows Phone 8.1** to be installed.

[image]

If didn't installed Emulators for Windows Phone 8.1 you can do so in Program and Features -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Change.

Comment: Just wanted to say that you won't see 8.1 emulators if you have this.  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" /> I changed 10.0 -> 8.1 and the emulator options popped.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong:

- The Windows Phone 8.1 emulators provided by **VS2015** are *only* good
  for testing Universal Windows apps (**APPX**) and nothing else.
- Windows Phone 8.1
  *legacy* apps (**XAP**) can only be emulated by installing the [Windows Phone 8.1 Updated Emulators](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719) separately.

You won' find this piece of information anywhere on the MS reference sites.