# VS2015 RTM. Cannot deploy application on Windows Phone with build target Windows Phone 8.

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

This was working on VS2015 RC.

Select target 'Windows Phone 8'.
Select 'Device'.

Right Click on project -> select 'Deploy'
   or 
Click on 'Debug' in toolbar

---

Error:
2>------ Deploy started: Project: XXXX, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone 8 ------
2>No Windows Phone 8 emulators installed.  Please install Visual Studio 2013 with the Windows Phone 8 tools selected to install the emulators.

### Build has been canceled.

I didn't select emulator ???

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you get the 8.1 emulators with 2015, which should work for you. See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526579/vs-community-2015-no-windows-phone-emulator-installed

Comment: I want to deploy on device not on emulator.
And when I select target Windows Phone 8 - I cannot choose WP8.1 emulator.

Comment: With your phone connected, what happens when you use Debug > Windows Phone (Universal) > Device?

Comment: Universal app is deployed and debugging starts. This is not what I want. I need target WP8. Barcode scan plugin is working for WP8 only not for target windows.

Comment: Same problem here. Something new?

Comment: As a workaround, you might try installing the Windows Phone 8 SDK, if you haven't already: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx. If you have already installed it, are you able to deploy to emulators (even though you want to target a device)?

Comment: FYI - in the VS product team we think we have a fix for this issue, we'll share it out soon and I'll post an answer to this question with a link to the update.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, this error was a bug in the product which is fixed in the [Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova Update 3 release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/06/now-available-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-update-3.aspx).